# Search text in elastic search ignoring uppercase and lowercase alphabet

Tags: elasticsearch

First of all i am new to elastic search. I have field `skillName:"Android Sdk"`. I map this field as `keyword` in elastic search. But problem is that when i search by something like

```
POST _search
 {
 "query": {
 "match" : { "skillName" : "Android sdk" } 
 }
}
```

`sdk` is small in search query. It does not give me any result. How can i search ignoring lower or upper case of text when field is mapped as keyword

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's ignoring the case different from the original, since you used [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html) analyzer, which didn't do anything with the token, but rather preserving it as it is. In your case it will do a match only if you query exact **same** token

So, I would propose to change this behaviour and at least apply [lowercase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html) token filter, so you will be able to match terms with different register.

Answer (score 1):

To search case insensitive on a keyword field you need to use a `normalizer`, which was introduced in 5.2.0. See [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/wildcard-case-insensitive-query-string/75050/5) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply different analyzers to same « field » and have one for full text search and another one for sorting, aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "skillName"
      ],
      "query": "Android sdk"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check this - https://discuss.elastic.co/t/wildcard-case-insensitive-query-string/75050/5